# Multiple Lists Mailchimp

Tags: wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I have a client who has 3 seperate rss to email campaigns that I setup in mailchimp and I have set up 3 feedburner feeds related to the 3 categories on his WordPress Blog.

Mailchimp recommends that we use 1 signup form per list/campaign but having 3 seperate forms in his sidebar is not an option. My client wants 1 signup form with the option to subscribe to each list on the form!

I have found this post by mailchimp but it is not very helpful at all... http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/signup-forms-for-multiple-lists

My question is this? Is is possible to have 1 form with the option to subscribe to all or just 1 list and if so how do I go about it?
Many thanks.

- Phillip Dews

Answer (score 0):

The answer: don't use multiple lists. Use one list and [interest groups](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/groups-and-segments/add-groups-to-a-list). Doing it that way has two benefits:

First, subscribers who want to receive multiple mailings won't be counted multiple times for billing.

Second, you can make use of checkboxes on the basic form to handle which RSS campaign to receive.

Comment: That looked perfect then, however each group/list needs to be for each campaign and it does not give that option!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Every campaign you create you can choose a segment of your list to send to, just choose a segment of only users who are in the correct interest group.